# (Surprisingly challenging?) Numpy Vectorization

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I want to find a way to **avoid the loop** in my code. I need to implement the following formula, which is at first straightforward:

[image: formula]

In words: A list of indices is parsed called **I**. For every index specified in **I**, the values of all following indices in the array **x** need to be subtracted. Do some calculations on the subtracted value. Sum everything up. Done.

My current code:

```
def loss(x, indices):
    """ 
    Args:
        x: array_like, dtype=float
        indices: array_like, dtype=int

    Example:
        >>> x = np.array([0.3, 0.5, 0.2, 0.1, 1.2, 2.4, 2.8, 1.5, 3.2])
        >>> indices = np.array([0, 2, 3, 6])
        >>> print(loss(x, indices))
        21.81621815885847
    """

    total = 0.0
    for index in indices:
        # Broadcasting here, as all values from all following indices have
        # to be subtracted from the value at the given i index.
        difference = x[index] - x[index + 1:]

        # Sum all up
        log_addition = 1.0 + np.log(np.abs(difference))
        total += np.sum(log_addition)

    return total
```

The challenging part is that the **'i'** indices are spread randomly over the range of the output. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one with NumPy-based vectorization -

```
mask = indices[:,None] < np.arange(len(x))
v = x[indices,None] - x
vmasked = v[mask]
log_addition = np.log(np.abs(vmasked))
out = log_addition.sum() + mask.sum()
```

Alternatively, using the laws of log, we can replace the final two steps with -

```
out = np.log(np.prod(np.abs(vmasked))).sum() + mask.sum()
```

Pushing the `abs` out, so that it operates on a scalar instead, it would be -

```
out = np.log(np.abs(np.prod(vmasked))).sum() + mask.sum()
```

Again, we can leverage `multi-cores` with `numexpr` -

```
import numexpr as ne
out = np.log(np.abs(ne.evaluate('prod(vmasked)'))) + mask.sum()
```

If you find that even `v` has too many unwanted elements, we can directly go to `vmasked` with -

```
xi = x[indices]
x2D = np.broadcast_to(x, (len(indices),len(x)))
vmasked = np.repeat(xi,mask.sum(1))-x2D[mask]
```

Comment: Thanks! This is already a nicely working solution. I was neverthelesse hoping to find a way to avoid the unnecessary computations which get cancelled out again, as I need to repeatedly apply this function many times and therefore need it to be as efficient as possible. I should have pointed that out in my question.

Comment: @fabriz-io Check out edits. It does those math heavy computations only on the relevant/valid elements.